# Populate column based on other column values using multiple if else

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to compare 4 columns in a pandas dataframe and populate 5'th column based on the result. In normal SQL it would be something like this:

```
if speciality_new is null and location_new is null then 'No match found'
elif specialty <> specialty_new and location <> location_new then 'both are different'
elif specialty_new is null then 'specialty not found'
elif location_new is null then 'location not found'
else 'true'
```

I read that this could be achieved using np.where but my code is failing. Can someone please advice me what I'm doing wrong. This is what I wrote:

```
masterDf['Match'] = np.where(
    masterDf[speciality_new].isnull() & masterDf[location_new].isnull(), 'No match found',
    masterDf[speciality] != masterDf[speciality_new] & masterDf[location] != masterDf[location_new], 'Both specialty and location didnt match',
    masterDf[speciality] != masterDf[speciality_new], 'Specialty didnt match',
    masterDf[location] != masterDf[location_new], 'Location didnt match',
    True)
```

The error message is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'` which doesn't make any sense since '&' is the syntax for 'and'

dfsample is what I have and dfFinal is what I want

```
dfsample = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       'speciality': ['doctor', 'nurse', 'patient', 'driver', 'director'],
       'location': ['texas', 'dc', 'georgia', '', 'florida'],
       'speciality_new' : ['doctor', 'nurse', 'director', 'nurse', ''],
       'location_new': ['texas', 'alaska', 'georgia', 'maryland', 'florida']})

dfFinal = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       'speciality': ['doctor', 'nurse', 'patient', 'driver', 'director'],
       'location': ['texas', 'dc', 'georgia', '', 'florida'],
       'speciality_new' : ['doctor', 'nurse', 'director', 'nurse', ''],
       'location_new': ['texas', 'alaska', 'georgia', 'maryland', 'florida'],
       'match': ['TRUE', 'location didn’t match', 'specialty didn’t match', 'both specialty and location didn’t match', 'specialty didn’t match']})
```

Comment: 'and' is the syntax for and.

Comment: Even 'and' didnt work. this is what is said in stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe, with expected output

Comment: You need to use the open and close parenthesis to ensure you got the query correctly mapped.

Comment: @sammywemmy added the sample dataframe and also the final output that I want

Comment: @JoeFerndz I tried adding paranthesis but still getting the same error. Also, thank you for the edits.

Comment: You're using multiple conditions in the `numpy.where` function, but it expects just one, alongside its output as parameters. You should use `numpy.select`, a nested `numpy.where` (with calls of `numpy.where` as the last argument from the function up to the default desired output), or simply use a Python built-in if-elif-else statement with `map` or `apply`, as provided in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For analyzing multiple conditions using `numpy`, you're better using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), where you should specify the conditions, the expected output for each condition, and a default output, just like an if-elif-else statement:

```py
import numpy as np

condlist = [
    dfsample['speciality_new'].isnull() & dfsample['location_new'].isnull(),
    dfsample['speciality'].ne(dfsample['speciality_new']) & 
    dfsample['location'].ne(dfsample['location_new']),
    dfsample['speciality'].ne(dfsample['speciality_new']),
    dfsample['location'].ne(dfsample['location_new']),
]

choicelist = [
    'No match found',
    'Both specialty and location didnt match',
    'Specialty didnt match',
    'Location didnt match'
]

dfsample['match'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=True)
print(dfsample)
```

where [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) stands by "not equal" (you can simply use `!=`).

---

Output:

```
   ID speciality location speciality_new location_new                                    match
0   1     doctor    texas         doctor        texas                                     True
1   2      nurse       dc          nurse       alaska                     Location didnt match
2   3    patient  georgia       director      georgia                    Specialty didnt match
3   4     driver                   nurse     maryland  Both specialty and location didnt match
4   5   director  florida                     florida                    Specialty didnt match
```

Comment: Hi @caina, thank you for helping out with this problem. I'm using the same code - with slight modification - but getting an error ```ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 63311, placement implies 1``` Can you please give any hint what can be the issue. 63311 is the number of rows in dataframe.

Comment: The code is
```condList = [
    dfsample['Address'].str.extract('(\d+)').isna(),
    dfsample['Address'].str.extract('(\d+)').replace(np.nan, -1, regex=True).astype(int)[0].eq(dfsample['street']),
    ]

choiceList = [False, True]

dfsample['match'] = np.select(condList, choiceList, default=False)```

Comment: Your first condition from `condList` returns a data.frame, where it's expected a Series or one-dimensional numpy array. If you place a `[0]` after it (like `dfsample['Address'].str.extract('(\d+)').isna()[0])` it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternate way to solve for it without the np.where. I am using apply function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       'speciality': ['doctor', 'nurse', 'patient', 'driver', 'director'],
       'location': ['texas', 'dc', 'georgia', '', 'florida'],
       'speciality_new' : ['doctor', 'nurse', 'director', 'nurse', np.NaN],
       'location_new': ['texas', 'alaska', 'georgia', 'maryland', 'florida']})

print (df)

def master_check(x):
    #print (x)
    if    (pd.isnull(x['speciality_new'])) & (pd.isnull(x['location_new'])): return 'No match found'
    elif  (x['speciality'] != x['speciality_new']) & (x['location'] != x['location_new']): return 'Both specialty and location didnt match'
    elif  x['speciality'] != x['speciality_new']: return 'Specialty didnt match'
    elif  x['location'] != x['location_new']: return 'Location didnt match'
    else: return True

df['Match'] = df.apply(master_check,axis=1)
```

The output will be:

```
ID speciality location speciality_new location_new
0   1     doctor    texas         doctor        texas
1   2      nurse       dc          nurse       alaska
2   3    patient  georgia       director      georgia
3   4     driver                   nurse     maryland
4   5   director  florida            NaN      florida


ID speciality  ... location_new                                    Match
0   1     doctor  ...        texas                                     True
1   2      nurse  ...       alaska                     Location didnt match
2   3    patient  ...      georgia                    Specialty didnt match
3   4     driver  ...     maryland  Both specialty and location didnt match
4   5   director  ...      florida                    Specialty didnt match
```

If you do want to use `numpy.where()`, then you have to consider each False statement as a separate `numpy.where()`. To implement it using `numpy.where()`, you have to do it this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

masterDf = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       'speciality': ['doctor', 'nurse', 'patient', 'driver', 'director'],
       'location': ['texas', 'dc', 'georgia', '', 'florida'],
       'speciality_new' : ['doctor', 'nurse', 'director', 'nurse', ''],
       'location_new': ['texas', 'alaska', 'georgia', 'maryland', 'florida']})


masterDf['Match'] = np.where(
    ((masterDf.speciality_new.isnull()) & (masterDf.location_new.isnull())), 'No match found',
    np.where(((masterDf.speciality != masterDf.speciality_new) & (masterDf.location != masterDf.location_new)), 'Both specialty and location didnt match',
    np.where((masterDf.speciality != masterDf.speciality_new), 'Specialty didnt match',
    np.where((masterDf.location != masterDf.location_new), 'Location didnt match',
    True))))

print (masterDf)
```

The output will be:

```
   ID speciality  ... location_new                                    Match
0   1     doctor  ...        texas                                     True
1   2      nurse  ...       alaska                     Location didnt match
2   3    patient  ...      georgia                    Specialty didnt match
3   4     driver  ...     maryland  Both specialty and location didnt match
4   5   director  ...      florida                    Specialty didnt match
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. Selected Caina answer because it looked cleaner and was smaller.